# Confusion between 濡れ羽色 and 烏羽色

Tags: meaning

According to a website I was learning, they said 濡れ羽色 is jet black and 烏羽色 is glossy black. But in my Japanese dictionary, both words mean glossy black?

Comment: I think most native speakers do not know these color names, and cannot explain the difference. Are you sure you need these words? (for example, are you interested in classical Japanese literature, becoming a color coordinator, ...)

Comment: @naruto haha then probably I should just stick to basic colors.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that, unless you're in a paint shop, you're expecting a bit too much from a dictionary.  According to my Japanese dictionary (ie, dictionary for Japanese written in Japanese), these words are practically identical.

The meaning of 濡れ羽色

> 水に濡れた烏の羽の色のように，しっとりとしたつやのある黒色
>   The color black having a moist gloss as in the color of a crow's moistened feather.

The meaning of 烏羽色

> 烏の羽のような，つやのある黒色
>   The color black having a gloss [and the color] like that of a crow's feather

Comment: I second that. See this article in Japanese: http://irocore.com/nureba-iro/

Comment: @A.Ellett Gotcha. Thank you for your answer ;)